# Can't select android as target in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-ndk, visual-studio-mac

I have just installed Visual Studio for Mac (On Mac OS X 10.12.1) and I'm trying to target android with no luck in xamarin forms neither native projects. The Android option is greyed.

If I go to Preferences -> SDK Locations -> Android:

- Android SDK
- Java SDK
- Android NDK

are installed and their path is known by Visual Studio (The three checks are green).
Any idea why is this happening?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing this issue as well. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm waiting for a more polished version of Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

"The iOS and Android options will be disabled if neither Xamarin.iOS nor Xamarin.Android is installed. If you install those components then these options should be available.

If you look in the about dialog's Show Details page that should indicate what you have installed."

[REF](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/392918/cant-select-target-platform.html)

Comment: You should specify in blockquotes material than you have copied, and add value via an explanation.

Comment: This is an old question of the days where Visual Studio for Mac was in Beta and didn't work correctly. This issue had gone in next revissions. Anyway thanks for answering